# buscador de string? C++

Tags: c++

Hola buenas estoy haciendo un proyecto, en este proyecto me impiden usar arreglos de chars entonces uso strings y tengo que realizar un buscador dentro de una lista, entonces por ejemplo el usuario busca por nombre "hol" y yo tengo un nodo de nombre "hola" le tiene que aparecer al usuario(y cualquier nodo que empiece por "hol") entonces esa es mi duda que funciones necesito para tal algoritmo Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el método find de la clase string.
Puedes indicarle la posición a partir de la que buscar. Cada vez que encuentra una ocurrencia debes avanzar para comenzar a buscar desde la siguiente posición. En caso de no encontrar ninguna ocurrencia devuelve string::npos.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "hola caracola como va";
    string texto = "ola";

    size_t pos = 0;
    while (pos != string::npos) {
        pos = str.find(texto, pos);
        if (pos != string::npos) {
            cout << pos << endl;
            pos++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```